# Maximum-Likelihood-Estimator for urn-problem

Tags: probability, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

Let $n \in \mathbb Z$. An urn contains three balls, one has the number $n$ and the two others have the number $n+3$. One ball is drawn randomly and it has the number X. On the basis of X, n is to be estimated.

Now we have $\Theta := \mathbb Z, \mathcal X:=\{n,n+3\}, \mathbb P(X=k)=\frac{1}{3}\mathbf 1_{\{k=n\}}+\frac{2}{3}\mathbf 1_{\{k=n+3\}}$.

I don't know how to calculate the maximum likelihood estimator for n here. More precisely, I don't know how to formulate the likelihood function in this case. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likelihood function is equivalent to the probability of seeing $X = x$ given that $n = \eta$, and is given by

\begin{align*}
L(\eta \, | \, x) & = \mathbf{P}[ X = x \, | \,n = \eta] \\
& = \frac{1}{3}\mathbf{1}(x = \eta) + \frac{2}{3} \mathbf{1}(x = \eta + 3).
\end{align*}

The maximum likelihood estimate $n^*$ is then the choice of $\eta$ which maximizes the above function. Note in particular that the above equation means

$$L(\eta \, | \, x) = \begin{cases}
\frac13 & \text{if $\eta = x$,} \\
\frac23 & \text{if $\eta = x-3$,} \\
0 & \text{else.}
\end{cases}
$$

Hence the MLE is given by $n^* = x - 3$.